# How to inject a List of Locales from header "accept-language" with JAX-RS?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jax-rs, resteasy

I have defined an Endpoint with JAX-RS (RestEasy) and would like to inject the List of Locales provided by the header parameter `"accept-language"`.

Example request header:

```
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
```

In this code the List contains only the first locale provided by the header of the send request but not the complete list.

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

@GET
@Path("/test")
public void getHeaderLanguages(@HeaderParam("accept-language") List<Locale> locales) {
    //output 1 Locale: en_GB,EN
    locales.forEach(System.out::println); 
}
```

This code prints the whole list of langues (as required) but the API is a bit clumsy.

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
public void getHeaderLanguages(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    Enumeration<Locale> localesEnumeration = request.getLocales();
    while(localesEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        //prints all 4 locales as expected en_GB. en. en_US. de
        System.out.print(localesEnumeration.nextElement() + ". "); 
    }
}
```

Is there a way to inject the List of all Locales send in the request header `"accept-language"` with the simple syntax close to the first approach but with the complete result like in the second example?

Comment: There’s always `List<Locale> locales = Collections.list(request.getLocales());`.

Comment: Thats a short convertion, yes. But I want to inject only the required dependencies. Injectng the request makes all other fields accessible as well and makes it unclear from the method signature what is actually used.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a perfect solution yet.

Currently I go with injecting the `HttpHeaders`. It gives me access to the required list of languages but does not give me access to the whole `HttpServletRequest`.

```
@GET
public void getLanguages(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    List<Locale> acceptableLanguages = headers.getAcceptableLanguages();
    // ...
}
```

Still open for a better solution.